# Synchronizing web application users with corporate directory/database

Tags: user-management, synchronization, federated

We're building a web app positioned towards corporations; and have a need to maintain an up to date repository of user data for all corporate users of our web application. We're well aware of how to achieve federated authentication - however we have a need to also maintain a local repository of metadata about a user (think department, position, level, etc) as well as be aware of the lifecycle of users (i.e. if someone has left the company etc), i.e. we need to solve provisioning.

What are best ways to ensure we can synchronize our user repository with *arbitrary* company repositories (e.g. typically LDAPs such as AD or similar)?

A few approaches we've considered:

- Setting up an LDAP query "pull" from our web app; that regularly
  polls for user data. Obviously may create a lot of unnecessary data
  shuffling (when nothing have changed), require an externally
  (internet) exposed LDAP server from the company which is not ideal
  security wise.
- Asking our customers to set up an LDAP synchronization
  engine on their LDAP servers (e.g. install an agent that pushes
  changes to us) - not ideal as it requires custom installed components & maintenance
- Build support for common (?) protocols for
  provisioning of users and tie in to some enterprise identity
  management solution (e.g. SCIM, SPML). What is actually in use
  today?

Any tips  / best practices?

Comment: This sounds incredibly broad, and is possibly the wrong approach from the outset.  Not everyone uses LDAP or AD, for example, and those that do (and know what they're doing) often synchronize their AD or LDAP with an authoritative employee database (usually some piece of crap HR picked).  For that matter, not everyone has an electronic employee database or directory, and not everyone who does is going to use the same one, or be willing to expose it to your web app.  So... well, those are some pretty big problems to address.

Comment: This is more of a programming architecture question than a sysadmin question. Should be moved to SO.

Comment: Maybe use Stormpath https://stormpath.com/product/ldap/

Comment: Stormpath link is now: https://stormpath.com/product/ad-ldap/